# Use Mockito to check that method gets called with different values

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin

im quite familar with Mocktio. But never needed something like this before:

Within my Test i like to verify that a method gets called with several values that represent a kind of "loading started". lets say "loading started" and "loading finished with result T". The order of those state change matters!

So, in pseudo code it would do something like this:

```
resultObject ...
clientcode.requestDataload()
// Order of below state changes is imporant
verifyThat(resultObject.data).wasCalledWith("loading started")
verifyThat(resultObject.data).wasCalledWith("loading finished with result T")
```

Thanks for pointing me into some direction.

Comment: Hey, did you finally try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the verifiy method from Mockito:

```
verify(mockInstance, times(1)).method(ArgumentMatchers.eq("what you want"))
```

where `method` is the method that the call need to be checked, and the ArgumentMatchers are the arguments passed to the method for the call (you can use `any()` too).

Comment: No sure this works, as my resultObject.data is finally in the state of "loading finished with result T", but i also want to verify that it was before in the "loading started" state

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`InOrder`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.27.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#in_order_verification):

```
val inOrder = inOrder(yourMock)
inOrder.verify(yourMock).yourMethod("loading started")
inOrder.verify(yourMock).yourMethod("loading finished with result T")
```